# GnuPG: How to encrypt/decrypt files using a certain key?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

**Long story short, my question is:** How can I force GnuPG which private/public key to use when encrypting/decrypting files?

---

## Some explanation / Long story

I have an application that must encrypt files before sending them to S3.

Users can download their files using their browsers from my website, in which case I must first decrypt the files before serving them.

Client side (**delphi 2010**): I'm most likely going to opt for [OpenPGPBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/)

Server side (PHP 5), I need to figure out how to encrypt/decrypt files with non-interactive commands.

I installed GnuPG on my server, tried this code:

```
clear_file='/full/path/my-file.zip'
encrypted_file='/full/path/my-file.zip.pgp'

# Encrypt file
/usr/bin/gpg2 --encrypt "$clear_file"

# Decrypt file
/usr/bin/gpg2 --decrypt "$encrypted_file"
```

But it seems that I can't specify, in the commandline, which keys to use.

Each user will have its own public/private key, so I need to be able to specify which key to use to encrypt/decrypt the file in question.

**My question is:** How can I force GnuPG which private/public key to use when encrypting/decrypting files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The options you are looking for are:

```
--default-key $name$
          Use $name$ as the default key to sign with. If this option is not used, the default key is
          the first key found in the secret keyring.  Note that -u or --local-user overrides  this
          option.
--local-user $name$
   -u     Use  $name$  as  the  key  to sign with. Note that this option overrides --default-key.
```

or possibly:

```
--recipient $name$
   -r     Encrypt for user id $name$. If this option or --hidden-recipient is not specified, 
          GnuPG asks for the  user-id unless --default-recipient is given.
--default-recipient $name$
          Use  $name$  as default recipient if option --recipient is not used and don't ask if 
          this  is a  valid  one. $name$ must be non-empty.
```

These can be used to specify who is the intended recipient, e.g. which public key to use for signing/encryption. When decrypting the files GnuPG automatically selects correct key if it exists in the current keyring, which can be selected with `--keyring` option, if multiple exist. GnuPG can be also configured to fetch necessary keys from a keyserver if they are available there.

You might be also interested in option `--batch` which makes sure that no interactive questions are asked during excecution.

I suggest you read through the GnuPG man page. There are lot of options that might be useful now and then.

Comment: Thank you, yes I read the man page (and **got lost**). I tried this command: `/usr/bin/gpg2 -v --decrypt --default-key "private-1.pgp"  /full/home/my-file.7z.pgp` but I got this `gpg: public key is 745ECDED
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 745ECDED
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key`...care to share an example command please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also used the `--local-user` switch and using full path for the private key file, but it didn't help

Comment: It might be that the key is not found in the keyring. I'm not completely sure if you can give the key in that way. Try first importing key to the key ring with `gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import private-1.pgp`and then decrypting with it: `gpg --decrypt my-file.7z.pgp`. If this is not working, test from command line, not from php, to rule out problems with environment variables etc. Other option is that there is something wrong with the key file.

Comment: @TheDude, [I posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20581497/902825) with some links/info that may be helpful with `--local-user`; seems that this is ONLY an override for _signing_.  (The older version of gpg I have _does_ say this is also for decrypt, but it was dutifully ignoring that nice option!)