# Dynamically load/use private PGP key, use it to decrypt data, then unload it from keyring

Tags: php, encryption, amazon-ec2, gpgpu, gnupg

This is a continuation of a previous question ( [GnuPG: How to encrypt/decrypt files using a certain key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292196/php-gnupg-how-to-encrypt-decrypt-files-using-a-certain-key) ), I need to:

1. **Dynamically load a private PGP key** (that is specific to a particular user) and import it into the keyring
2. Decrypt some data using this key
3. Unload this private key & erase any trace of it

This may seem like a complicated way to decrypt data, suffice to say that I have strong reasons to do that. I may be wrong but I can't just decrypt files by supplying the private key via the commandline (this would be perfect but it seems I can't do that), ie.

```
exec("gpg --use-key=private-key.gpg -o $clear_file_name --decrypt $encr_file_name");
```

So, **how can I dynamically load/use private PGP key**, use it to decrypt data, then **unload it from keyring**

**OR** (if this is not possible), are there any other similar tool that allows me to achieve this?

**PS. The code will be run on a linux EC2 instance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use gpg's `--homedir` option, i.e. with a temporary dir that you can delete afterwards. See [this answer at superuser](https://superuser.com/a/450760) for an example.