# GPG - decrypt with multiple recipients

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I am trying to decrypt a file that has been encrypted using 2 recipients (--recipient recipientA@example.com --recipient recipientB@example.com).
However when I try to decrypt the file, it always requests the passphrase of the 1st recipient. When the 1st recipient secret-key isn't part of the key-ring, it will give an error 'secret key not found'.

How can I encrypt a file with multiple recipients so that both can decrypt them without knowing eachother keys & passphrases?

(To me, the question seems simple and a basic feature - but obviously I cannot get it to work)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems like this has been resolved. In gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.11, gpg will first check whether you have the private key and then ask for the passphrase only if you have it, which is obviously the reasonable order ;)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem today, and found your question looking for the answer.  I've seen many merry an example of how to *encrypt* things for multiple recipients... never saying/showing what will happen when one tries to *decrypt* that data.  Here's what I got:

```
user@system ~ $ gpg --decrypt filename.pgp

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "SOMEBODY ELSE <somebody_else@example.com>"
2048-bit ELG-E key, ID ABC1234, created 1972-10-29 (main key ID ABC5678)

gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ... [I DON'T HAVE *THEIR* PASSPHRASE!]

2 more times... finally...

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "HEY!  This is ME! <my_email@example.com>"
2048-bit ELG-E key, ID DEF1234, created 1969-02-03 (main key ID DEF5678)

gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit ELG-E key, ID ABC1234, created 1972-10-29
      "NAME <email@example.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: bad passphrase
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit ELG-E key, ID DEF1234, created 1969-02-03
      "HEY!  This is ME! <my_email@example.com>"

and then the file decrypted fine...
```

*Quick Note:* Just to clarify, [for security reasons](http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/) one's passphrase and one's [private key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) should **NEVER** be given to anyone else.  [The passphrase is to keep the private key "safe" should it become compromised.](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c481.html)  One's *public* key is the only thing that should be shared with others.

I preface this with the fact I currently only have access to version 1.4.2.2, and don't have the ability to test these solutions.  Later version have certain options that may well be what's needed.  ***Please try and answer back if any of these work.***

`--local-user/-u` looked promising.  In the version I have, `--help` showed [`use this user-id to sign or decrypt`](http://www.csc.gatech.edu/~copeland/6612/pgp/gpg_quick_help.txt)  But when trying it seemed futile, further research revealed a cruel truth: [seems the help is wrong](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gnupg/users/4848#4848), and this is ONLY an option using for ["signing"](http://gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html).

[This post](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gnupg/users/51238#51238) has a likely solution, though I personally find it messy:

```
gpg --try-all-secrets --passphrase <passphrase here> filename.pgp
```

`--passphrase` [was apparently added in version 1.4.3](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2007-August/031711.html).  UGH!

**EDIT:** [Perhaps a better (possibly, below) solution is only available in gpg2?](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html)   [`gpg2 seems to have`](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/GPG-Key-related-Options.html#GPG-Key-related-Options) `--try-secret-key`, which if I read correctly, may be what we're both looking for?

Comment: Very good research. Thanks. There is one other option, for which convenience will depend on your use-case. You can use the option --secret-keyring and pass a (temporary) keyring to gpg with the right key in it. This way you can externalize the decision out of gpg (eg. you could write a wrapper script around gpg).

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this problem today and I have solved it by running gpg in batch mode:

`/usr/bin/gpg --batch --passphrase "your_passphrase" --verbose --decrypt`